# LIST directories in Snowflake STAGE from S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From Snowflake Docs of [LIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html)

> Returns a list of files that have been staged

Example like

```sql
list @my_csv_stage/analysis/ pattern='.*data_0.*';
```

Is it possible to *LIST* **directories** under the list path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object storage like S3 don't actually have directories. It only seems that way sometimes because the object names use forward slashes and common text between slashes to look like a directory structure. (Azure Blob storage may be different, or may have a construct to simulate directories. In either case, it's not captured in a stage.)

[This answer at Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3#:%7E:text=Directories%20don%27t%20actually%20exist,like%20dirA%2FdirB%2Ffile%20.) does a good job of explaining.

So given that there are no directories, only parts of object names that simulate the look and feel of directory paths, it would be necessary to LS all objects in a stage, extract the simulated directory paths, and aggregate them to the unique values.

This would be okay for stages without too many objects, but if there are a lot the LS will be slow. The distinct aggregation will be a little slow, but just listing the objects will be what takes the most time.

```
ls @MY_STAGE;

set quid = (select last_query_id());

select distinct regexp_substr("name", '^(.*[\\\\\\/])') as DIRS
from table(result_scan($quid));
```